# Why can't Swift infer the contextual base type in a result builder?

Tags: swift, dsl

Background: I'm writing a compiler for a toy language in Swift, and I want an elegant way to create ASTs for my language. The AST type for a statement in my toy language looks like this:

```
indirect enum Statement {
    case assignment(variable: String, expression: Expression)
    case conditional(`if`: Expression, then: Statement, `else`: Statement)
    case loop(`while`: Expression, `do`: Statement)
    case sequence(Statement, Statement)
    case noop
    case halt
}
```

Right now, if I want to write the AST for a series of statements, I would have to write:

```
// let's say I want to represent a series of 4 no-ops:
.sequence(.noop, 
    .sequence(.noop, 
        .sequence(.noop, 
                      .noop)))
```

That looks very verbose. I thought it would be nice if I could use the `@resultBuilder` feature, so that I can write:

```
Statement {
    .noop
    .noop
    .noop
    .noop
}
```

This is my attempt:

```
@resultBuilder
struct StatementBuilder {
    static func buildBlock(_ components: Statement...) -> Statement {
        if components.isEmpty {
            return .noop
        } else {
            return components.dropFirst().reduce(components.first!) { x, y in .sequence(x, y) }
        }
    }
}

extension Statement {
    init(@StatementBuilder block: () -> Statement) {
        self = block()
    }
}
```

However, this gives me the error:

> Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'noop'

in the `Statement { ... }` block.

What is unclear about the contextual base? What type can it be, other than `Statement`? I could fix this by prefixing everything with `Statement.`, but that's too verbose. What else can I do?

---

Note that I also plan on overloading operators so that I can easily create assignments and expressions, conforming the syntax tree types to `ExpressibleXXXLiteral`, and adding `If` and `While` functions taking `StatementBuilder`s, which create `.conditional` and `.loop` statements. So the result builder will be far more useful than just for creating no-ops and halts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears ResultBuilder expressions use something called one-way constraints

Holly Borla explains [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/function-builder-cannot-infer-generic-parameters-even-though-direct-call-to-buildblock-can/35886/3):

> Yeah, this is expected behavior. The type inferred for an expression
> in a function builder does not affect the types inferred for the other
> expressions.
>
> Unlike most expressions in Swift, function builders use something
> called one-way constraints for type inference (this is why a regular
> function call to buildBlock behaves differently wrt type inference). A
> one-way constraint means that type information can flow only in one
> direction, instead of the usual bi-directional type inference. So, in
> this case, the type information Conv2D will affect the overall
> type inferred for model, but not for the other expressions inside
> Sequential { ....
>
> @Douglas_Gregor wrote up an explanation of one-way constraints and why
> they're used in his PR that added them:
> https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/25983

Answer (score 2):

Your calls to `.noop` are expressions.
So you need to add the following to your `StatementBuilder`

```swift
static func buildExpression(_ expression: Statement) -> Statement {
  expression
}
```

Though when you have multiple noops you'll run into the error
`Enum case 'noop' cannot be used as an instance member`

So each expression will need to use semicolons to end it. Like so:

```swift
Statement {
    .noop;
    .noop;
    .noop;
    .noop;
}
```