# How to do a Tuple extension in current Swift? It seems to be available experimentally

Tags: swift, tuples, swift5

Some code,

```
typealias Brio = (String, String, String)

extension Brio {
    static var divider: Brio {
        return ("_", "_", "_")
    }
    static var isDivider: Bool {
        return (self.0 == "_")
    }
}
```

> Tuple extension must be written as extension of '(repeat each Element)',

> Tuple extension must declare conformance to exactly one protocol

> Tuple extensions are experimental

[image]

I really couldn't figure it out from say this chat,

https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-user-defined-tuple-conformances/67154

---

I don't understand the following sort of stuff but if relevant:

```
fattie@m2max203mbp16 ~ % swift --version
swift-driver version: 1.90.11.1 Apple Swift version 5.10 (swiftlang-5.10.0.13 clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx14.0
fattie@m2max203mbp16 ~ %
```

---

### Coin use case:

Here's an example of where extending tuples would be sweet

```
// Setup the screen selector button
screensButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
let noms = [
    Brio("CA", "Cats", "cat.fill"),
    Brio("DO", "Dogs", "fido.circle"),
    Brio("DO", "Horsies", "equine.circle"),
    .divider,
    Brio("DEV", "Dev reload", "link"),
    Brio("DX", "Dev, clear", "circle"),
    .divider,
    Brio("XX", "Example", "circle.dotted"),
    Brio("XX", "Example", "link"),
]
var elements = noms.chompchomp(){ k in self.screensButtonProcess(k) }
screensButton.menu = UIMenu(children: elements)
```

[image]

Having to use a class is annoying. It would be more purer with tuples, eg,

```
let noms = [
    ("CA", "Cats", "cat.fill"),
    ("DO", "Dogs", "fido.circle"),
    ("DO", "Horsies", "equine.circle"),
    .divider,
    ("DEV", "Dev reload", "link"),
```

Footnote, here's the kodes for `chompchomp`, done with tears as a class `Brio` rather than tuples:

```
///A "BUTTON TRIO". Internal code, title, system image.
///
///Use `[Brio]` to make menus. Just put `.divider` where you want dividers.
///
///OR just use `buildBrios { }` if using the matching @resultBuilder
struct Brio {
    let c: String
    let t: String
    let i: String
    var isDivider: Bool = false
}

extension Brio {
    init(_ x: String, _ y: String, _ z: String) {
        self.init(c: x, t: y, i: z)
    }
    ///When you type-out a `Brio` array just put `.divider` where you want dividers.
    static var divider: Brio {
        return Brio(c: "_", t: "_", i: "_", isDivider: true)
    }
}

extension [Brio] {
    ///Chew on an array of `Brio` and spit out the UIMenuElement array. Recall that to create dividers in UIKit menus, basically each run (other than the first) is marked as inline.
    func chompchomp(with: @escaping (_ tapped: String)-> ()) -> [UIMenuElement] {
        var brios = self
        var result = brios.chomp().elements{ b in with(b) }
        var run = brios.chomp().elements(with: { b in with(b) })
        while !run.isEmpty {
            result.append(UIMenu(options: .displayInline, children: run))
            run = brios.chomp().elements(with: { b in with(b) })
        }
        return result
    }
    ///Simply give the next run of menu items removing that run.
    mutating func chomp() -> [Brio] {
        let spl = self.split(maxSplits: 1, whereSeparator: { $0.isDivider })
        self = (spl.count < 2) ? [] : Array(spl[1])
        return (spl.count < 1) ? [] : Array(spl[0])
    }
    ///Alchemize one run of Brio into an array of UIMenuElement.
    func elements(with: @escaping (_ tapped: String)-> ()) -> [UIMenuElement] {
        return self.map({ brio in
            return UIAction(title: brio.t, image: UIImage(systemName: brio.i)) { _ in
                with(brio.c)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

---

<sup>* it's hilarious that *cat.fill* actually exists!</sup>

Comment: I don't have Swift 5.10 to try this yet, but based on the error messages, the extension must be on *all* tuple types, not just `(String, String, String)`. You need to handle any number of tuple elements. Also, the extension must be conforming tuples to a protocol. And, it looks like you also didn't turn on the feature flag for this.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for that - flag good one.  I *think* I have 5.10 (notice question edit).  I added that info to the Q.  *You need to handle any number of tuple elements* , right, I have absolutely no idea how to use the apparently suggested syntax (*"as extension of '(repeat each Element)' .."*) and after messing with it for an hour I gave up and hit SO.

Comment: Yeah, I know you have Swift 5.10. I meant *I don’t*, so I could only give you some suggestions based on the error messages. Bottom line is, you cannot do this with a tuple extension. In your case, it only makes sense to have this extension for 3-element triples, but the tuple extensions language feature *require* you to write extensions for any number of tuple elements.

Comment: Now that you made your ultimate goal clearer, I can think of some alternatives. How about using a macro to generate the code for creating an array of `Brio`s? Basically, keep the struct, but with a macro, you can still use the tuple syntax, and the macro will convert the tuple syntax to some struct initialiser calls.

Comment: Or, you can use a custom `@resultBuilder`. This allows you to put these tuples in a closure, and the result builder converts them to a `Brio`. This changes the syntax at the use site, but it’s very similar.

Comment: @Sweeper I am thrilled that apparently Swift now has macros, I love macros, I have not had a chanmce to look in to them yet!  Good call.  I will investigate  resultBuilder - maybe it needs an answer?

Comment: PS I had no clue I was using 5.10 swift until you mentioned the issue and I googled how to determine what Swift I was using  :[ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions on tuples must conform tuples of any number of elements to a protocol. Your use case only makes sense to use 3-tuples, so a tuple extension isn't very suitable.

You should keep your `Brio` struct, and create a result builder for `Brio`s,

```
@resultBuilder
enum BrioBuilder {
    static func buildExpression(_ expression: (String, String, String)) -> Brio {
        let (c, t, i) = expression
        return Brio(c, t, i)
    }
    
    static func buildExpression(_ expression: Divider) -> Brio {
        Brio.divider
    }
    
    static func buildBlock(_ components: Brio...) -> [Brio] {
        components
    }
}

func buildBrios(@BrioBuilder block: () -> [Brio]) -> [Brio] {
    block()
}
```

Then you can achieve a usage like this:

```
// noms will be of type [Brio]
let noms = buildBrios {
    ("CA", "Cats", "cat.fill")
    ("DO", "Dogs", "fido.circle")
    ("DO", "Horsies", "equine.circle")
    Divider()
    ("DEV", "Dev reload", "link")
}
```

You cannot use the `.divider` syntax in a result builder (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70224957/5133585)). You can write `Brio.divider`, or use a separate struct (I have borrowed the `Divider` from SwiftUI here).

You can extend this further by implementing `buildArray`, `buildIf`, etc in the result builder. This would allow you to use loops and if statements in the result builder closure. For more information, see the [Swift Evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md).